# Unable to upload video from iPhone with paperclip-ffmpeg in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ffmpeg, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I upload a video from an iPhone, I'm getting the following error:

```
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/6da355e988ec841811d8803dfd5cf44c20150513-8103-b4lkam.MOV'
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename IMG_2637.MOV (["video/quicktime"]), content type discovered from file command: inode/x-empty. See documentation to allow this combination.
(0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 400 Bad Request in 58ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
```

**(This works perfectly when I upload the same video from desktop.)**

I used gems  `"paperclip", "~> 4.1"` and `"paperclip-ffmpeg"`.

In my video model:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :student_video, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
```

also tried out

```
validates_attachment_content_type :student_video, :content_type => ['video/x-   
#                                        msvideo', 'video/avi', 'video/quicktime', 'video/3gpp', 'video/x-ms-
#                                        wmv', 'video/mp4', 'flv-application/octet-stream', 'video/x-
#                                        flv', 'video/mpeg', 'video/mpeg4', 'video/x-la-asf', 'video/x-ms-asf']
```

But I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Paperclip thinks you're uploading spoofed media.

Here's a workaround I found here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1429

```
require 'paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector'
module Paperclip
  class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
    def spoofed?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

You're basically monkey-patching Paperclip's MediaTypeSpoofDetector class to ensure that it doesn't check for spoofing.

Comment: thanks Nickm. I tried out above solution but result is same that i m anable to upload video as mention above.